# python pull Queue

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using a back end handler to collect URL's from  site maps. I am using a pull queue to perform this task and task constructor did not allow to add a url to it 's constructor. How to add a URL to a Pull queue so once the task is complete i can use REST to retrieve it's status. can any one give me a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the documentation on the task queue REST API: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest.html

Specifically, you can use

```
GET
https://www.googleapis.com/taskqueue/v1beta1/projects/{PROJECT_NAME}/taskqueues/{TASKQUEUE_NAME}/tasks/{TASK_NAME}
```

If the object is returned, it will have info on whether it was leased (started) or not. If nothing is returned, that means that task is done.

Please note, the documentation states that this API is experimental, so I would consider using built-in ways of managing the queue.